# Slicing surfaces in solides3d

Tags: pst-solides3d

Is it possible to slice surfaces (`psSurface` mind you) in `pst-solides3d`? It is quite impressive to see the slicing mechanism on other solides (as described in the manual) but I have stumbled upon an error

this is as far as I've come

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\psset{viewpoint=50 20 30 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,Decran=40,solidmemory}
\psSurface[
    incolor=gray,
    ngrid=.25 .25,
    action=none,
    plansepare={[0 0 1 1]},
    name=silla
](-2,-2)(2,2){x y mul}
\psSolid[object=load,load=silla0]
\composeSolid
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The error that is spewed out is the following

> (ps2pdf) Error: /rangecheck in -putinterval-

I guess my question could be summed up to

- Am I doing this wrong?

or

- Is it not possible to cut a surface the way I'm trying to

My final goal is to generate an image similar to the one below where the red lines represent the sliced portions of the surface

[image]